# Serialized object is output with strange symbols

Tags: php, html, serialization, anchor, href

```php
<?php
class test {
  private $a;
}

$test = new test;
$test = serialize($test);
echo "<a href=$test>$test</a>";
```

A string from the resulting markup:

```php
<a href="O:4:&quot;test&quot;:1:{s:7:&quot;�test�a&quot;;N;}">O:4:"test":1:{s:7:"testa";N;}</a>
```

Question: why the value of the same variable output as a value of href attribute is seen WITH these � symbols while placed as content of the anchor tag is seen WITHOUT these � symbols?

Comment: NUL bytes around private properties. Depends on how/where you inspected the HTML. Browser, Firebug, hexeditor?

Comment: You might want to check the charset

Comment: @mario Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit), dev tools.

Comment: @SuperDJ UTF-8. What do you mean by checking? =)

Comment: @olegzhermal well the `?` you're getting may sometimes be caused when the charset is not right. So when the charset doesn't have that character it will return all kind of other weird characters like the question marks

Comment: @SuperDJ But if the problem is encoding, then there would be these question mark symbols in both cases (href value and content) because it's the same variable... Or not?

Comment: @olegzhermal yes should be there in both cases